# Tab size of QTabBar in QMdiArea

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtabbar, qmdiarea

My QMainWindow is using QMdiArea. The viewMode of the QMdiArea is set to TabbedView. The Tab size of MdiArea takes entire width of the MdiArea:

[image: 1 tab]

If more tabs are added, they divide MdiArea width and consume entire width:

[image: More tabs..]

I understand that the MdiArea in tabbedView uses QTabBar, but I'm not able to find a way to set MdiArea's TabBar setExpanding property to false.

Any clue (Qt, PyQt or PySide) will be helpful.

Comment: `mdiArea.setViewMode(QMdiArea.TabbedView); tabs = mdiArea.findChild(QTabBar)`.

Comment: This approach worked. I'd like to accept this as answer, if you can add as answer please. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped - I have now added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab-bar of a [QMdiArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html) can be accessed, but there's currently no public API for it. A work-around is to first ensure the [view-mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmdiarea.html#viewMode-prop) is set to `TabbedView`, and then use [findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) to get the `QTabBar` object. It will then be possible to change the [expanding property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#expanding-prop) of the tab-bar:

```
mdiArea.setViewMode(QMdiArea.TabbedView)
tabs = mdiArea.findChild(QTabBar)
tabs.setExpanding(False)
```